# show div dependent on value

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to show or hide a div based on the overall value of my selects:

Here is a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/wrfvukjv/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function recalculate() {
    var sum = 0;
    $("input[type=radio]:checked").each(function () {
        sum += parse($(this).val());
        });
    $("#sum").html(sum.toFixed(2));
}

$("input[type=radio]").change(function () {
    recalculate();
});

</script>
```

I have tried here:

```
if (sum > 2)
{
    console.log('showmessage');

} 
else
{
    console.log('no message');
}
```

but it just returns no message

Comment: What are the conditions to show or hide the div?

Comment: @james_bond i have added my attempts into the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is you updated [**jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/wrfvukjv/7/)

Javascript :

```
function recalculate() {
    var sum = 0;
    $("input[type=radio]:checked").each(function () {
        sum += parseFloat($(this).val());
        });
    $("#sum").html(sum.toFixed(2));
    if(sum >= 2) $("#message").show();
    else $("#message").hide();
}

$("input[type=radio]").change(function () {
    recalculate();
});
```

And HTML for your message:

```
<div id="message">
  Show message IF overall sum is >= 2<br>
  Hide if < 2
</div>
```

And a little bit of CSS for hide the `#message` when page load:

```
#message {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: It works until you deselect, so if i show it, then change my options the message still stays?

Comment: `if(sum >= 2) { $("#message").show(); } else { $("#message").hide(); }`

Answer (score 1):

You can add a condition at the end of your `recalculate()` function:

```
function recalculate() {
    var sum = 0;
    $("input[type=radio]:checked").each(function () {
        sum += parseFloat($(this).val());
        });
    $("#sum").html(sum.toFixed(2));

    if(sum >= 2){          
        $("#message").show();
    }else{
        $("#message").hide();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can be done with less code also. See below. 
`#message` is initially hidden and when `:radio:checked` sum of value is  greater than or equal to 2, you show `#message`

**CSS**

```
#message{
  display:none
}
```

**JQUERY**

```
var sum=0;
$("input[type=radio]").change(function () {
    sum=sum+parseInt($(this).val());//ASSUMING VAL TO BE INT ONLY
    sum>=2?$("#message").show():$("#message").hide()
});
```

[**WORKING FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/5fuakt1v/8/)